# PostGIS raster query "out of range raster coordinates"

Tags: postgis, raster, raster2pgsql

I have a large raster (national scale) that I have loaded into PostGIS using raster2pgsql and a 100x100 tile size: `raster2pgsql -I -C -s 27700 my.tif -t 100x100`.  I am now trying to query a large number of points to find the raster values at each location (values are held in a separate decode table keyed by the pixel value), my query is as follows:

`INSERT INTO raster_values
SELECT p.id, d.*
FROM my_point_table p
JOIN my_raster r ON ST_Intersects(p.the_geom, r.rast)
JOIN my_raster_decode d ON (ST_Value(r.rast, p.the_geom) = d.value);`

However when I run the query every so often I get a warning from PostGIS:

`NOTICE:  Attempting to get pixel value with out of range raster coordinates: (28, 100)
NOTICE:  Attempting to get pixel value with out of range raster coordinates: (64, 100)
NOTICE:  Attempting to get pixel value with out of range raster coordinates: (100, 1)
NOTICE:  Attempting to get pixel value with out of range raster coordinates: (100, 17)`

The presence of a 100 in every error would indicate there is an issue with the bounds I am using but I am struggling to work out what I have done wrong.  I have checked the SRID of both the point and raster table and confirmed that these are consistent (27700):

`"enforce_srid_rast" CHECK (st_srid(rast) = 27700)
the_geom         | geometry(Geometry,27700)`

Comment: Sounds to me like the raster tiles are not actually in the right place... Do they appear at the correct co-ord location if you load them into a GIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
INSERT INTO raster_values
SELECT pt.id, d.*
FROM
   (
    SELECT p.id id, ST_Intersection(rast,1,ST_AsRaster(p.the_geom, rast),1) as intersectx,
    ST_Value(r.rast , p.the_geom) val
    FROM my_raster r, my_point_table p
    WHERE ST_Intersects(the_geom, rast)
    ) as pt,
    my_raster_decode  d
WHERE pt.intersectx IS NOT NULL AND pt.val = d.value;
```

ST_Intersects returns a true or false, it is not really joining, more filtering for where the geometries intersect.

**EDIT:**

I've edited the query adding a subquery to convert point to raster (for st_intersection) and also to calculate the ST_Value. Only Where this subquery  is valid will the result be tested against the '*my_raster_decode*' table.

If there is no intersection between the points and the raster then the query should return nothing, not just throw an error.

Comment: Thanks @cushen, this certainly makes for a neater query however unfortunately I am still seeing the same warnings.

Comment: @MarkV too bad that didn't work; I've edited the answer, hopefully it should now work. I've tried out and example with points that don't intersect a raster here locally and all seemed ok.

Comment: so sorry I completely missed your answer. It arrived as I stopped work for the Christmas holidays. I will be running the data load again this week so will try your suggested approach. Thanks so much for taking the time to help

Comment: Thanks so much @cushen for the detailed answer and sorry it has taken me so long to get back to this.  I was waiting on a new dataset which just arrived last week.  The solution works perfectly thank you

Comment: No worries @MarkV. Glad it worked out for you!