# Error with ST_Value, ST_NearestValue: out of range raster coordinates

Tags: postgis, raster

I have a UK 5m DTM coverage loaded into Postgis with:

```
raster2pgsql -s 27700 -I -C *.tif -t 100x100 ....
```

which looks more or less like the below for a full 1000 x 1000 pixel tile, before tiling:

[image]

This works as expected, however when I run a query for ST_Value, such as:

```
SELECT ST_Value(rast, geom, true) 
  FROM terrain_5, addresses 
 WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, geom) 
   AND address_id = xxxx;
```

I get the error:

> NOTICE:  Attempting to get pixel value with out of range raster coordinates: (2, 100)

If I run the same query, but using **ST_NearestValue** instead I get two rows back, eg,

```
-3.40282346638529e+38
 70.7099990844727
```

I have checked for the points where this happens and they are always round numbers divisible by 500.

If instead I request the metadata, ie, the same query but using **(ST_MetaData(rast)).*** I get two rows,

upperleftx | upperlefty | width | height | scalex | scaley | skewx | skewy | srid  | numbands

166500 |      27500 |   100 |    100 |      5 |     -5 |     0 |     0 | 27700 |        1

166500 |      27000 |   100 |    100 |      5 |     -5 |     0 |     0 | 27700 |        1

It is pretty obvious that the problem is due to 100x100 tiles of pixel size 5m, resulting in edge conditions every time a coordinate being tested for intersection is divisible by 500.

I have solved the problem by rewriting the above query using **max(ST_NearestValue(rast, geom))**, ie,

```
SELECT max(ST_NearestValue(rast, geom, true) 
  FROM terrain_5, addresses 
 WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, geom) 
   AND address_id = xxxx;
```

the final parameter makes no difference, as there are no no data values in the coverage, as can be seen from the input raster.

If I run the histogram, excluding, no data, I get and add up the values:

```
SELECT sum(count) 
  FROM 
      (SELECT 
            (ST_Histogram(rast, 1, true, 10)).count 
         FROM terrain_5, addresses
        WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, geom) 
         AND address_id = xxxx
      ) foo;
```

I get 20000, ie, the sum of the pixels in both the intersected tiles that intersect the point divisible by 500.

I have seen [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265829/postgis-raster-query-out-of-range-raster-coordinates), but I don't think it really answers my case.

I have a solution, using **max(ST_NearestValue(rast, geom))**, but this does strike me as unexpected behaviour, or I am missing something really obvious. Sadly, when I ran this on the national dataset, the value that was chosen from the two results was the low one, so I have a lot of houses whose height above sea level is -3.40282346638529e+38, when even by British standards of building in flood plans, strikes me as excesssive. I only noticed when looking at summary statistics after the fact, as my original update query swallowed the errors.

Comment: just a thougtht; does it make a difference if you use a true `CROSS JOIN` (it shouldn´t, though, *but the binding is strong in you, young `CROSS JOIN`....*)?

Comment: @ThingamaBob. It doesn't, no. I would be quite concerned if it did, as I have always understood that the , is rewritten as CROSS JOIN by the query planner.

Comment: yeah, I know...it only makes a difference for referencing tables in multiple joins by condition. why does `ST_NearestValue` return two rows? can you get a `ST_Value` if you use *columnx*, *rowy* instead?

Comment: @ThingumaBob. I have no idea why it returns two rows (this is the point of my question :-)), and more to the point, why one of them is -3.40282346638529e+38. It seems like an out by one error based on tiling.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really an answer as such but I think I have experienced this bug too and have reported it [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/4051#no1).

It could also be something in one of the underlying libraries.

I will see what else I can do to try and debug.